# Closure and interior of subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

a) Let $X = C_b(\mathbb{R})$ thse set of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. We have the subset $Y = \{f \in X : f(t)= f(t+1)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R} \}$. $Y$ is closed relative to the uniform norm, so we have $Y = \bar Y$, where $\bar Y$ is the closure of $Y$. I have already proven this. Now I want to figure out what the interior of $Y$ is, i.e. $\mathring Y$. I think $\mathring Y = \emptyset$, but I've not been be able to prove this.

b) Let $X = C[0,1]$ and $Y = \{f \in X:\exists f'(0), f'(0) = 0 \} \subset X$. $Y$ is not closed relative to the uniform norm, I have found a counterexample, therefore $\bar Y = X $. I have no idea what $\mathring Y$ is.

If anybody could give me a hint how to prove my assumptions or correct me, I'd be glad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mark where a new subtask starts. a) consider $f\in Y$ and $f(t)+\epsilon·\sin(t)$.

Comment: A closed linear supspace of a Banach space $X$ either coincides with $X$ or has empty interior.

Comment: For $Y$ you probably mean "the derivative at 0 exists and equals 0"?

Comment: In case of b), yes, that's what I meant.